# Checked radio button in React / Redux not working

Tags: reactjs, redux

Can someone help on the below?

I am wandering why my checked radio button is not working.

The part in FFCleaning.js where there seems to be a bug with the radio button is this part:

checked={appearClean === 'Y'}

I am trying to use Redux to help achieve the below. I tried using state management, but that doesn't seem to work in a class.

FFCleaning.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {handleAppearClean } from 'redux.js'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faAngleDoubleRight, faAngleDoubleLeft } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'


class FFCleaning extends Component {
  onNextClickHandler = () => {
    this.props.history.push('/ff-report/FFRepairs')
  }
  render () {
    const  {handleAppearClean, appearClean} = this.props;
    

    return (
        <div>

          <h2 style={{textDecoration: "underline"}}>Cleaning</h2>

          <label>Does this property appear to be clean?</label>
          <div>
            <input type="radio" id="appear_clean_yes" name="appear_clean" value="Y" onChange={handleAppearClean} checked={appearClean === 'Y'}></input>
            <label htmlFor="appear_clean_yes">Yes</label>

            <input type="radio" id="appear_clean_no" name="appear_clean" value="N" onChange={handleAppearClean} ></input>
            <label htmlFor="appear_clean_no">No</label>
          </div>

        </div>
    )
  }
}

FFCleaning.propTypes = {
  handleAppearClean: PropTypes.func,
  appearClean: PropTypes.string,
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => bindActionCreators({
  setClient,
  handleAppearClean
}, dispatch)
```

Redux.js:

```
  const actions = {
  APPEAR_CLEAN_FLAG: 'SELECTEDFFAPPOINTMENT/APPEAR_CLEAN_FLAG',
}

const initialState = {
  appearClean: '',
}

const setAppearClean = (appearClean) => ({
  type: actions.APPEAR_CLEAN_FLAG,
  appearClean
})

const handleAppearClean = (event) => (dispatch) => {
  const { value } = event.target
  dispatch(setAppearClean(value))
}


export {
  actions,
  handleAppearClean
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i have always struggeled with onChange action with radio buttons and i have now kind of a hack for it i always use onClick event on a radio button instead of onChange and it has really helped me hope it helps you to what i would have done here is that i would send the value directly onClick of radio rather than sending an event on onChange let me show you what i mean

```
     <input type="radio" id="appear_clean_yes" name="appear_clean" onClick={()=>handleAppearClean("Y")} checked={appearClean === 'Y'}></input>
            <label htmlFor="appear_clean_yes">Yes</label>
```

this would be my onClick while the handleAppearClean function would be changed as well so it receives string value instead of an event

```
const handleAppearClean = (value) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(setAppearClean(value))
}
```

hope this helps

Comment: I think what I have done so far - achieves the same as you. Its just the bug with the 'checked' on the radio button.

Comment: I have noticed, that appearClean is coming back as undefined....

Comment: have you tried mapping state to props i didn't see any map state to pros function for mapping redux state to props